# Update record in database to be equal to user input with JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, jdbc

I have a JSP page where the user selects an event from a drop down and then types in a start date and an end date into two text boxes.

I have an oracle database to store the data in.  How would I set up an Update statement to look at the event selected from the drop down list, and then update the start date and end date for that event to be equal to the user input?

Basically, how would I create an update statement to accomplish the below results?

```
update = "UPDATE event_times SET start_date = '(user input in start date box)' WHERE event_id = (event selected from drop down)";
update = "UPDATE event_times SET end_date = '(user input in end date box)' WHERE event_id = (see above)";
```

Comment: show us what have you done so far and what problem you are facing...

Comment: When I tried to copy over some of my code the formatting was messed up in the window so I copied over the majority of it.  I can establish a database connection, however am having trouble updating the start date and end date.   As it is right now, I select an event (spring, january summer all, etc) from a drop down menu.  Then I type a start date and an end date for the event into a text box.  I want to update the record to reflect those start and end dates.

Comment: @BobSmitherson Update the Question itself when you have more information rather than post comments. Notice the "edit" link just below your Question, on the left (if using a web browser to view this). But don't change the nature of your Question.

Comment: By the way, for an entirely different way to use a drop-down list (pop-up menu) to enter a row in a database in a web app built with Java, see [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52340226/642706) to this other Question, using the [*Vaadin*](http://www.Vaadin.com/) framework.

Answer (score 1):

why are you using two update queries when you can do the same with single query

Assuming your selected start date = 1st Nov 2014

selected end date = 30th Nov 2014

selected event id = 10 then your query will looks some thing like this

Oracle query:

```
UPDATE event_times SET 
start_date = TO_DATE('2014/11/01 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'), 
end_date = TO_DATE('2014/11/30 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') 
WHERE event_id = 10;
```

MySQL query:

```
UPDATE event_times SET 
start_date = '2014-11-01', 
end_date = '2014-11-30' 
WHERE event_id = 10;
```